# Is the pullback functor $q^*$ essentially injective when $q$ is a regular epimorphism?

Tags: category-theory, pullback, epimorphisms

Let $q : W \rightarrow V$ be a regular epimorphism in a category $\mathcal{C}$, and consider the pullback functor $q^* : \mathcal{C}/V \rightarrow \mathcal{C}/W$. Is $q^*$ necessarily essentially injective? That is, does $q^*C \cong q^*D$ imply $C \cong D$?

Context: I'm trying to get a better understanding of Schulman's stack semantics (https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3802, definition 7.2). Given two objects $A,B$ in $\mathcal{C}/U$, we can consider the statement $U \Vdash (A \cong B)$; I wanted to know whether this is equivalent to just the statement that $A \cong B$. (Note: the formula $A \cong B$ is shorthand in categorical first order logic for $(\exists f : A \rightarrow B)(\exists g : A \rightarrow B)((g \circ f = \operatorname{Id}_B) \wedge (f \circ g = \operatorname{Id}_B))$.) If the answer to my question is "yes", then this equivalence becomes rather easy to show.

I know that it would be sufficient to show that $q^*$ is full and faithful. I suspect that the answer to my question is "no", because there doesn't seem to be any straightforward way to prove it. However, I don't have a good repertoire of examples that would allow me to construct a counter-example. If necessary, we can make additional assumptions on $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: This would for instance be true in a slightly weaker sense if $\mathcal{C}$ was a topos. In the situation of that paper by Shulman, a $\Pi$-pretopos would suffice. The statement would be that, if you have a morphism $f\colon C\to D$ already that becomes an isomorphism after pulling back, then $f$ is an isomorphism. Is this enough for you?

Comment: I think there might be a typo in defining the (co)domain of $f$ and/or $g$ in the definition of $\cong$